# Distance between 2 Google Map points

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I have a HTML page which has 2 textboxes and a button.

My question is, is it possible to get a google map popup when the first textbox is clicked to allow the user to select a start point, after which the user closes the popup and selects the second textbox to get the google map popup again to select the end point on the map.

After that the user should be able to click the button and should be displayed the number of miles between the 2 selected points via the quickest road travel route possible.

Comment: You can do this using markers very easily .

Comment: hey...the mosquitokiller...if it is very easy, just provide the answer, or a reference...instead of making a non-helpful comment about it being easy...the person is not asking ease or difficulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier as you may think. In Google Maps API v3, there is this

```
var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pointA,pointB)
```

method you can use, where pointA and B are markers.

Make sure you include the **geometry** library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

Method documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en-US&csw=1#spherical

Comment: Doesn't it calculate the displacement? How do I calculate the traverse-able distance between pointA & pointB?